# Homestead Installed PHP7 but I need PHP5

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead, php-7

Homestead randomly stopped working for me, so I tried to remove the whole thing and reinstall, but it's not gone well.

I have it "running" after a day and a half of muddling my way through various issues. However, for reasons that I cannot understand, my Homestead box is now running PHP 7.

[The instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead) I was following had *optional* options for installing PHP 7, but I intentionally skipped that because we are on PHP 5.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to fix this. Things I have tried:

- I have destroyed and reinstalled the box multiple times.
- I have deleted the VirtualBox box multiple times and redownloaded it.
- I tried installing v0.3.3 of the box based on one suggestion. (I also updated the homestead.rb script accordingly.) At one point, something failed during the install process with `php7.0-fpm: unrecognized service` and the configured sites were returning 502 Bad Gateway errors.
- After reinstalling with v.0.4.0, it has started "running" as I described (serves the sites as expected, etc.), but with PHP 7.

Searching for solutions has persistently led to a dead-end.

I'm just a dummy front-end developer. :) Laravel, Vagrant, Homestead, all this stuff makes my head hurt. I just want this to work again so I can go back to my actual work. Any advice or alternate avenues of pursuit for researching this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: So thing with vagrant it downloads image that has most of stuff already installed. You can try different image. https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=php . Or you can always ssh to your box and manage it there ;)

Comment: Why not just work with php7? If the code works and runs fine, use it. It is quite the improvement over php5.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn in my case, I have to deal with a legacy project and I was trying to accomplish this, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been through this issue too and I solved it by installing an old homestead box v0.3.3 and I've used an old release of homestead installer, so I suggest that you remove your current box v0.4.0 and delete your homestead folder then do this:

```
$vagrant box add laravel/homestead --box-version 0.3.3
```

and then download an older version of Homestead installer from git, I'm using [v2.1.8](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases/tag/v2.1.8) it works fine.
Enjoy php 5.6 :)

Comment: I tried this, when running `vagrant up` it searches for box `0.4.0`, doesn't find it and starts downloading.

Comment: delete your box and try this command: 
$vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.3.3/providers/virtualbox.box

Comment: I know this is old now but did you ever get around it trying to download the latest homestead even after the vagrant box add 0.3.3? I downloaded it all and then when i run vagrant up it starts downloading the latest one anyway but i also want php5.6...tried downloading and using the linked v2.1.8 and it still does the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where I tried to upgrade Homestead to the most recent Homestead 7.0 box and configure it to run PHP 5.6 instead of PH7, which various sources said was possible via adding a line to the .yaml file specifying the PHP version.

```
sites:
- map: myproject.local
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/craven/public_html
  php: "5.6"
```

What actually happened when I tried that was that I got a 502 CGI gateway error. Here is a summary of the steps I had to take to fix it:

1) SSH into the Homestead virtual machine.

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

Taking a look at the nginx error log in /var/log/nginx/ reveals that the PHP 5.6 files the server is looking for don't exist.

You can get confirmation of this by having a look at the executables.

```
ls -la /usr/bin/php*
```

2) To install PHP 5.6, run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm
```

You can confirm that the php 5.6 service is running via the command

```
service --status-all
```

3) Once all this is working, refresh the web page for your site and it should now work. In my case, because I was running a Laravel 4.2 site, I then to install Mcrypt:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt
```

4) In order to get my mysql database up and running, I also had to install mysql.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql
```

And of course after all that, I had to re-import the database contents from the file I'd exported before upgrading the Homestead box.

Note that if you ever destroy and recreate the Homestead box, you will need to repeat all these steps again.